# Regex Pattern to find blank space

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

This is a single field value and has to be split based on blank lines.

```
Eg:

abc street 
xyz 
city 785263 

lmn street 
abc 
city 462738
```

I tried  AddressList = addresses.split('\n{2}') but dose not work.

Comment: Use `addresses.split('\\s')`.

Comment: @arut blank lines, not just blanks?

Comment: @sfdcfox My bad [+1 to your ans]. I ran only by the title before commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addresses.split('\n{2}')` only works if it's actually just newlines (`\n`). There are three common newline connections, LF (`\n`), CR (`\r`), and CRLF (`\r\n`).

To be compatible with all of these, try:

```
addresses.split('(?m)\\s*^\\s*$\\s*')
```

This has several parts:

```
(?m) multiline mode enabled
\\s* zero or more whitespace
^ Beginning of a line (multiline mode)
$ End of a line (multiline mode)
```

So: "In multiline mode, find any spaces followed by any start of line, with any spaces, then an end of line, followed by any more spaces."

Or, you could replace CRLF and Cr to just LF, then your original code should work:

```
addresses.replaceAll('(\\r\\n|\\r)','\n').split('\n{2}')
```

Comment: addresses.replaceAll('(\\r\\n|\\r)','\n').split('\n{2}') Thanks, it worked.